# How do I parse a json Array string with restassured from(), with a root array?

Tags: json, spring, rest-assured

How do I parse json like this:

```
[{"name":"joe","address","Main Street"}]
```

with the from() method in restassured:

```
assertEquals(true, from(myjson).getString("name"));
```

I get this error:

[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: Is your json just a String? It seems like your parser is expecting XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be you're using [`XmlPath.from()`](http://rest-assured.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.0/apidocs/com/jayway/restassured/path/xml/XmlPath.html#from%28java.lang.String%29) instead of [`JsonPath.from()`](http://rest-assured.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.0/apidocs/com/jayway/restassured/path/json/JsonPath.html#from%28java.lang.String%29), so it's trying to parse your JSON as XML.

Comment: That was it!  Eclipse had pulled in "...xml.XmlPath.from" instead of "...json.JsonPath.from;" in the imports.